# change display setting on headless server using command line

Tags: screen, display-resolution

running a headless acer ac100 server with xubuntu 16.10. The display settings seem to be 640x480 (or worse) and I can't work out how to change them from a command line. I am accessing the server using noMachine. The installation is a vanilla Xububtu  16.10. The video is what came with the machine. I have googled this but not found anything helpful, so any and all suggestions welcome. Thanks in advance.

PS I am happy to change remote access software, nomachine was just the first remote desktop solution I found (in case the remote server is the issue)

Comment: A "headless" server is headless. It has no display and no keyboard. Whatever exactly it is that you want to change it cannot be the display settings of a headless server.

Comment: Depending on which noMachine implementation you are using, you should be able to specify the resolution of the connection on startup in the client. Other implementations also allow to resize the remote desktop on resize of the window. My best experience is with [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, the noMachine version is current this week. When I was setting up the NAS I had a screen connected and I could access it remotely at the NAS's set resolution. What seems to be happening is that the NAS, without a screen is set to VGA and noMachine can only use that resolution. Therefore changing the noMachine settings has no effect on the resolution. What I am trying to do is change the resolution the NAS uses and therefore the resolution noMachine uses. I will look at x2go.

Answer (score 0):

I use noMachine to connect to a headless system. Here're my notes:

```
# 2may18: setup bionic headless ...  use cvt 1280 1024 to get the modeline
# connect via nx, res is 1024x768, run the next 4 lines, reconnect with nx

xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x1024_60.00

sudo systemctl restart nxserver.service
```